# Kubernetes "shared" persistent volume on DigitalOcean

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, kubernetes-pod

I have a persistent volume defined as

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: ghost-cms-content
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: do-block-storage
```

and a deployment defined as

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: ghost-cms
spec:
  replicas: 4
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ghost-cms
      tier: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ghost-cms
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      topologySpreadConstraints:
        - maxSkew: 1
          topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/region
          whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
          labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: ghost-cms
              tier: frontend
      containers:
        - name: ghost-cms
          image: ghost:4.6-alpine
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2368
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/ghost/content
              name: content
          env:
            - name: url
              value: https://ghost.site
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 256Mi
      volumes:
        - name: content
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: ghost-cms-content
```

but each replica appears to have a unique volume that is not shared with the rest of the replicas. For instance, when I create a text file inside `/var/lib/ghost/content` in one of the pods, I don't see it in the volume of the other pods. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PVC with permission

```
accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
```

Each pod will get the one volume or PVC, as it's readwrite once.

If you want to keep shared volume across replicas you can use the **NFS** with **accessMode** **ReadWriteMany**

```
 accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
```

Read more at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes

Example : https://medium.com/asl19-developers/create-readwritemany-persistentvolumeclaims-on-your-kubernetes-cluster-3a8db51f98e3

You can also use **Minio**, **GlusterFS** to creeat the **NFS** or any managed service like **GCP filestore** providing **NFS** and attach that to POD.

GKE example : https://medium.com/@Sushil_Kumar/readwritemany-persistent-volumes-in-google-kubernetes-engine-a0b93e203180

Comment: I can see the files sync in `/var/lib/ghost/content` but I haven't tested with the pods running in different nodes. Are you saying that I wouldn't see a sync-ed PVC across nodes if I don't use NFS or GlusterFS?

Comment: There will be a single PVC and all your pods will get attached to it regardless of node.