# How to create a container/pod successfully mounted with PVC with Storage class created with a specific UID

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, containers, kubernetes-pvc, mounted-volumes

I have created a Storage class with Uid and Gid in mountOptions for a trident Storage class as below:

mountOptions:

- uid=1000
- gid=1000

And created assoicated PV and PVC with the newly created Storage Class. The PV and PVC are created successfully.
Then mounting to this PVC tried to create a pod but it is stuck at Container Creating phase with failed volume mount error in the Events of the pod.

Anything that needs to be done additionally for creating the pod successfully?

Comment: are you trying to attach multiple PODs to single PVC ?

Comment: in that case you might need use the ReadWriteMany access mode.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69430760/5525824

Comment: @HarshManvar I am using ReadWriteMany access mode only. The following is the event logged in the pod.

Warning FailedMount 8s (x6 over 25s) kubelet MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-69a577e9-b61e-4abd-9fa5-aaf07042fd68" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = error mounting NFS volume 10.226.0.44:/trident_qtree_pool_trident_WEKRFAIOKH/trident_pvc_69a577e9_b61e_4abd_9fa5_aaf07042fd68 on mountpoint /var/lib/kubelet/pods/e20272b0-7bda-452f-810e-72464841beca/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/pvc-69a577e9-b61e-4abd-9fa5-aaf07042fd68/mount: exit status 32